# Reproducir video con la etiqueta <video> HTML mediante PHP

Tags: php, html

estoy haciendo una app web con php, y estoy queriendo seleccionar un video y que me lo reproduzca. Tengo el siguiente codigo y me muestra hasta la interfaz del video pero no se me reproduce el mismo.

Estoy usando netbeans IDE 8.2 y xampp3.2.4 para la ejecucion. Me sale una noticia cuando hago la ejecucion en chrome, sobre la variable THE_FILE que no esta definida, la cual es el name del input en el cual cargo el video seleccionado. ¿como podría quitar ese aviso?

Y lo principal del problema es que se reproduzca el video mediante: echo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Edición de video</title>

    </head>
    <body>


        <div id="main-area">
            <div id="header">
                <h1>Please upload your video to edit it!</h1>
            </div>

           <div>
               <form action="Index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                   <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="20000000" />
                   <input type="file" name="the_file" id="the_file" />
                    <br>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload file" />
                </form>
            </div>

        </div> 

    <?php
        if ($_FILES['the_file']['error'] > 0)
        {
            echo 'Problema:';
            switch ($_FILES['the_file']['error'])
            {
                case 1:
                    echo 'File excede upload_max_filesize';
                    break;
                case 2:
                    echo 'File excede max_file_size';
                    break;
                case 3:
                    echo 'File only partially uploaded';
                    break;
                case 4:
                    echo 'No file uploaded';
                    break;
                case 6:
                    echo 'No puede subir archivo: no temp directorio especificado';
                    break;
                case 7:
                    echo 'upload failed: no write to disk';
                    break;
                case 8:
                    echo 'A PHP extension blocked the file upload';
                    break;
            }
            exit;
        }

        if ($_FILES['the_file']['type'] != 'video/mp4')
        {
            echo 'Problema: fichero no es MP4';
            exit;
        }

        $uploaded_file = 'C:\Users\juanmi\Desktop\TFG\Proyecto\media\-'.$_FILES['the_file']['name'];
        //$name = basename($_FILES['the_file']['name']);

        if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['the_file']['tmp_name']))
        {
            if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['the_file']['tmp_name'], $uploaded_file))
            {
                echo 'Problem: no se ha podido copiar al directorio deseado';
                exit;
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'Copiado al directorio deseado. Nombre archivo:';
                echo $_FILES['the_file']['name'];

            }
        }

        echo '<br>';
        echo '<br>';
        echo 'File uploaded successfully';
        echo '<br>';
        //mostrar lo transferido
        echo '<div align="center">';
        echo '<video width="600" height="300" controls autoplay>';
        echo "<source src='$uploaded_file' type='video/mp4'> ";
        echo 'Your browser does not support the video tag.';
        echo '</video>';
        echo '</div>';





    ?>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Estás tratando de acceder a un índice en `$_FILES` que solamente existe en caso de que el fichero se haya enviado mediante el `<form>`. Antes de tratar de acceder a un índice: `$_FILES['the_file']` se ha de comprobar que este exista:  `if(isset('$_FILES['the_file']')) { ... } `

Comment: he controlado ya con un  `if(!isset('$_FILES['the_file']')) { echo 'la variable esta vacía'; exit }` me devuelve como que la subida esta realizada correctamente pero sigo sin poder reproducir el video al final del programa. Gracias por contestar.